# how to select data on list property from observablecollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `ObservableCollection<CrawlerDetailModel>` which **CrawlerDetailModel** has a List property.

```
public class CrawlerDetailModel
{
    public List<EblaghPersonel> EblaghPersonel { get; set; }
    ...

}

public class EblaghPersonel
    {
        public string Vahed { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to get the items that have the specific text in Vahed property.

but i cant use this code

```
var items = DataList.Where(x=>x.EblaghPersonel.Vahed.Equals(Text)).ToList()
```

Because EblaghPersonel is a list property, So how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if any record exists in `Eblaghpersonel` that has a Vahed of `Text`:

```
var items = DataList.Where(x => x.EblaghPersonel.Any(ebl => ebl.Vahed == "Text"))
                    .ToList()
```